# Merge same named .txt file in different directories?

Tags: powershell, text, merge, command-prompt

I have a folder that is filled with sub folders of past dates (`20120601` for example), inside each date folder there is a file named `test.txt`, along with another file named `example.txt`. How can I merge all the `test.txt` files into one?

I am trying to do this in Windows and have access to Windows PowerShell and Windows Command Processor (`cmd.exe`). What would be the best way to do this?

My hierarchy would look something like this:

```
\Data
     \20120601
           test.txt
           example.txt
     \20120602
           test.txt
           example.txt
     \20120603
           test.txt
           example.txt
     \20120604
           test.txt
           example.txt
     \20120605
           test.txt
           example.txt
```

I would imagine it is something like

```
copy *\test.txt alltestfiles.txt
```

Is that possible? Can you specify a wildcard for a directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly easy, actually:

```
Get-ChildItem \Data -Recurse -Include test.txt |
  Get-Content |
  Out-File -Encoding UTF8 alltestfiles.txt
```

or shorter:

```
ls \Data -r -i test.txt | gc | sc -enc UTF8 alltestfile.txt
```

This will first gather all `test.txt` files, then read their contents and finalle write out the combined contents into the new file.

Comment: This did the job and it merged all the files exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

List all the files. Read one file's content and add it into the combined file. Like so,

```
cd data
gci -Recurse | ? { -not $_.psIsContainer -and $_.name -like "test.txt"}
$files | % { Add-Content -Path .\AllTests.txt -Value (Get-Content $_.FullName) }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple command like `cat path\**\* > target_single_file` also works.